# Can puffball spores survive freezing?

Tags: mushrooms, temperature

I'm trying to inoculate the yard with puffball scraps, and was wondering if the fresh spores on the lawn will be able to survive freezing so I can get several in the yard next year.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly - they would encounter freezing temperatures in nature and the spores of many species are able to survive cryogenic temperatures.